# Consolidate .on function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `.on()` functions for separate dynamically added elements, they are:

```
$('body').on('click', 'img', function() {
   modal(content[$('li.active a').attr("href")].images[$("img").index(this)]);
});
$('body').on('click', 'img', function() {
   closeM();
});
```

The second function, I have shortened to

```
$("body").on("click", "#close", closeM);
```

In looking at the jQuery documentation for `.on()`, I saw that I can do something like:

```
$("body").on({
  click: function(){
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
  }
});
```

I was wondering if I could either do something like that with my previous two functions, or if there was any other way of shortening/combining them.

Comment: [JsFiddle: example of using selector for event map style of `on` method](http://jsfiddle.net/LU38z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do both operations inside the anonymous function (that you are sending as third parameter).

```
$('body').on('click', 'img', function() {
   modal(content[$('li.active a').attr("href")].images[$("img").index(this)]);
   closeM();
});
```

Also, I would consider simplifying the first instruction by breaking it down into smaller pieces.
All compressed together as it is, it is some serious black magic and should be quite tough to read or maintain by anyone else.

---

But `$("body").on("click", "#close", closeM);` is very simple, and also much more contained because it applies to the only element with id `#close` in the HTML, instead of to all the images. So I would prefer to leave it separate.

Comment: The only problem with putting the both events in the same `.on()` is that `closeM()` is called when a `div` with `#close` is called, instead of an image. So short of breaking up the parameters in the `modal()` call, there isn't much I can do?

Comment: I believe so. But then, if they apply to two different things I find it better that they are explicitly separate.